# React native automated push notification

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, amazon-sns

How do i automate the push notification in react native. (Firebase, AWS). Should work on Android as well as IOS. I have tried with manual pushing of notification. https://medium.com/@amisree/author-arafath-misree-cc5da85888ef

Please help me to do the same for automated one.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification
You can use this lib for scheduled notification.